# How implantation MKNN Algorithm In Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, knn, classifier4j

I have a problem

I need to Implantation of below article in Matlab but i can't find any source code of that.

[Article link](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCECS2008/WCECS2008_pp831-834.pdf)

I tried by myself but it's a little complex for me .

does anyone have Implantation of the article or can do it for me ?

Thanks too much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste, at least, your aforementioned trials.

Comment: `fitcknn` has a `'Distance'` property where you can specify a custom distance function. Have you tried using that? Please post a [mcve] showing what you've tried so far and how it isn't working correctly.

Comment: Yes , fitcknn has a "Distance" property ,but i don't know much how can i use it , if you look at this article you can find out what i mean , he made a voting system mix with weighting distance and gets better accuracy , I want implanting same thing like article i linked  in Matlab and measure accuracy at end too