# Make Custom Knn Classifiction in Matlab

Tags: matlab, classification, matlab-guide, knn

**Hi** , I research almost of pages in internet but i can't find solution of my problem . I describe it here maybe someone can help me , Please if you know answer help me because  its so critical issue for me .

I have a new method for calculation distance in Knn classification , I want implanting my idea in Matlab and edit original Knn and make work it with my Distance Calculation , but how can i edit it and put my distance method on it ??

please hellp me if you have any idea how can i  do that

**Thanks**

Comment: I assume this is the same problem as your previous question on MKNN. It would be better to edit the other question and add more detail. Asking the same question again is just going to attract downvotes. Please read [ask] and improve your previous question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How implantation MKNN Algorithm In Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40149331/how-implantation-mknn-algorithm-in-matlab)